# Filtering multiple nested array with SQL++ query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

In my bucket the documents have this structure

```
{
    "version" : 1,
    "root1" : "root1",
    "root2" : "root2",
    "i" : [
        {
            "i1" : "i1",
            "i2" : "i2",
            "p" : [
                {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "p2" : "p2",
                    "tr" : [
                        {
                            "id" : 1,
                            "x" : "VALID",
                            "check" : false
                        },
                        {
                            "id" : 2,
                            "x" : "INVALID",
                            "check" : false
                        }
                    ]

                },
                {
                    "id" : 2,
                    "p2" : "p2",
                    "tr" : [
                        {
                            "id" : 1,
                            "x" : "VALID",
                            "check" : true
                        },
                        {
                            "id" : 2,
                            "x" : "INVALID",
                            "check" : true
                        }
                    ]

                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

`i` is an array that contains the field `p` which is also an array and it contains also another array field `tr`

I want to return all document that have `tr.x = "VALID"` and `check = false` and eliminate from it `tr`that doesn't much this criteria.
So for the last example the return should be

```
{
    "version" : 1,
    "root1" : "root1",
    "root2" : "root2",
    "i" : [
        {
            "i1" : "i1",
            "i2" : "i2",
            "p" : [
                {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "p2" : "p2",
                    "tr" : [
                        {
                            "id" : 1,
                            "x" : "VALID",
                            "check" : false
                        }
                    ]

                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select:

```
SELECT *
FROM default
WHERE ANY a IN i
      SATISFIES
        ANY b IN a.p 
        SATISFIES
            ANY c IN b.tr 
            SATISFIES 
                c.x = 'VALID' AND c.check = false
            END
        END
      END
```

This simply nests the conditions for each nested array until the individual fields can be filtered.

*An approach* to returning only the matched array data is to apply similar logic:

```
SELECT OBJECT_PUT(default
                 ,"i"
                 ,ARRAY OBJECT_PUT(ii
                                  ,"p"
                                  ,ARRAY OBJECT_PUT(ppp
                                                   ,"tr"
                                                   ,ARRAY tttt 
                                                    FOR tttt IN ppp.tr 
                                                    WHEN
                                                        tttt.x = 'VALID' AND tttt.check = false 
                                                    END
                                                   )
                                   FOR ppp IN ii.p 
                                   WHEN
                                     ANY ttt IN ppp.tr
                                     SATISFIES
                                        ttt.x = 'VALID' AND ttt.check = false
                                     END 
                                   END
                                  ) 
                  FOR ii IN default.i 
                  WHEN 
                    ANY pp IN ii.p 
                    SATISFIES 
                        ANY tt IN pp.tr
                        SATISFIES 
                            tt.x = 'VALID' AND tt.check = false 
                        END
                    END
                  END
                 )
FROM default
WHERE ANY a IN i
      SATISFIES
        ANY b IN a.p 
        SATISFIES
            ANY c IN b.tr 
            SATISFIES 
                c.x = 'VALID' AND c.check = false
            END
        END
      END
```

which just replaces (the OBJECT_PUT functions) elements with filtered elements at each nesting level. The same element selection is repeated at each level since the filtering occurs on the elements before the OBJECT_PUT is applied.

Undoubtedly there are other approaches too.

HTH.